How to Map Language-Specific Versions of Static Pages to Different Services in Google App Engine?
I have a microservice based architecture on Google AppEngine (Python) and am facing trouble with having complex routes in dispatch.
I have two sets of static pages:

https://www.example.com/page
https://www.example.com/blog/page

I have /blog present in my dispatch to my "blog" service.
Now, I also have language version of said pages, the URLs for which are

https://www.example.com/de/page
https://www.example.com/de/blog/page

I have a handler for /de/ (and other languages) on my "default" service and am looking for a way to route traffic from /de/blog to my "blog" service.
Is there a way to do so?
Note that /blog/ and / have different sets of pages and even though I can render the language version of my "blog" pages from "default" service, I would prefer not to. I can also change the URLs of my blog version, but that is not advised by google for terms of SEO (and since that is off the scope on stackoverflow, let's not touch that)
Edit:
dispatch.yaml
dispatch:
  - url: "*/blog*"
    module: blog

Handler in my main.py file:
@app.route("/<regex('[a-z]{2}'):ll>/")
def ll_pages(ll):
    from .ll_pages import LLPages
    return LLPages


@app.route("/<regex('[a-z]{2}'):ll>/<path:sub_url>")
@route_call
def ll_pages(ll, sub_url):
    from .ll_pages import LLPages
    return LLPages

Note : I have the relevant routing in LLPages class which is working fine and serving multiple routes as I want like /de/pages, /de/images which are being served form the default service (as they should be).
I only want my /de/blog to go to different service.

show what you currently have in your dispatch.yaml file

the links are broken and the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

Hi, I did not provide the actual links because of security purposes.

@NoCommandLine I have edited my question to add dispatch routes.
